# 307: hackers temporary redirect for javascript files

Tags: networking, internet, http, spam-prevention

I have an http website, hosted by the service provider. My web pages load javascript files from the web server. Well, really standard scenario, but...

When I am at home, and load web page from my web server, I see banner ad. It must NOT be there at all, because I was programming the website manually, and all web pages are hand made, no automated website creation at all.

After some investigation I figured out that most of the time, when web page asks for .js file, the browser gets 307 redirect to spammer's website, which shows the ad.

The files on the web server are intact; and if I use another internet provider this issue does not exhibit - only when I am at home using very specific internet service provider.

I suspect that some gateway in the service provider's network was hacked, and it intercepts the http (insecure) requests and routes browser to the spammers.

Am I correct? What can I do in this situation? Is it possible to locate the malicious node on the network?

Comment: Anything is possible. It could be something on *your* system that chooses to behave differently depending on where it figures out it's running from. You'd need to setup some easily reproducible tests between your system, an other system (eg would a smartphone using your Wireless connection to the same ISP be affected? But then as it doesn't present itself as a computer, anything can change behavior too) and the server to try and narrow the possible cause.

Comment: I have two computers win Win of different versions, if connected to home network they both reproduce same redirects using different browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Opera), but when Opera is connected through VPN it does not happen, and when I am in another location (using another service provider) the problem also does not exhibit. So it is surely NOT a specific PC, but specific route of the data in the network.

Comment: First place to test could be the (home) router then. It can't see vpn's traffic so can't change it.